# How to check the date format as YYYYMMDD using Solaris shell command?

Tags: shell, date, sunos

I have searched all over but the option to display the date format in SunOS 5.10 is present, but no answers for how to check the valid format as per our requirements.

```
#!/bin/bash
date +'%Y%m%d' -d "$4" 2>&1 >> ${LOG_FILE}
is_valid=$?
if [ $is_valid -eq 1 ];then
   echo "Invalid date format"
   exit 2
fi
```

When I execute the command I pass the date in the option and if the date format is not correct the shell should exit.
This format check command is not working in SunOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the SunOS 5.10 version of `date` accepts the `-d` option. However, it does provide the `cal` command. As your date format is all digits, it is quite easy to split into year, month and day, feed the month and year into `cal` and then use `grep` to look for the day. Something like:

```
#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
        Y=${1%????}
        t=${1#????}
        m=${t%??}; m=${m##0}
        d=${t#??}; d=${d##0}
        if [ -n "$(cal "$m" "$Y" 2>&1 | grep "\<$d\>")" ]; then
            echo ok
        else
            echo no
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo no
        ;;
esac
```

Note: Untested, as I no longer have any Solaris 10 machines.

Comment: I can test it with bash, you are missing `)` after `$(cal`. Line above `esac` should be `;;`. Next start testing with input like `12321` and you find another bug.

Comment: @walter-a cheers. Yes, I typed this in very quickly. Is this any better? Does Solaris 10 have bash? I've forgotten. I suppose it doesn't matter as the questioner seems to have it.

Comment: I don't have Solaris. I think bash must be installed when you want it. Just using bash for a basic check, it looks better now.

Comment: @jhnc thank you for the solution, it worked in the Solaris bash, and also understood the logic.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people install GNU utilities, such as bash, in /usr/gnu/bin, or something like that. Sometimes, installing bash, either from source or a package might aid you with scripting.

I always replaced ksh with pdksh on Solaris, because it was a completely different syntax for scripting. I got tired of having to have two copies or rewrite everything. Same thing with bash.